# ibooks like carousel view

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I want to create and app with carousel kind of view, with images in rows and columns, where number of columns are fixed, but number of rows varies. when user clicks on an image it opens up a detailed view.
My initial approach is to used tableview, with one cell as a row, but here tricky part is calculating the column, which I am doing by tagging the views.
Is my approach is right or is there is any other better way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `AQGridView` to handle this I think

https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView

It works very similar to `UITableView` by using a `dataSource` and `delegate`